# Format a ext2/ext3 drive with open permissions

Tags: format

I need to be able to access an external hard drive on multiple linux computers. The drive needs to be formatted ext2 or ext3. How do I change the permissions after formatting in gparted. Or is there a much simpler option that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

For `ext*` drives, the permissions are set by the permissions of the mount point. They have nothing to do with the formatting tool. And this depends on the UID/GID combination that you use across the systems. If you can use the same UID/GID combination everywhere, you won't have a problem.

Otherwise, you can decide on a GID which is currently free on all your Linux systems, create a group corresponding to that everywhere, and `chgrp` the mount point and give it `g+w` permissions.

A safe bet with most modern systems is the UID/GID combination of 1000/1000 - the default user id  for most normal users. The safest bet is, of course, 0/0 - the root UID/GID. Certain to exist everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use gid 0. If all machines only have a few users then examining /etc/group by hand is easiest. If that proves a daunting task look at the file adduser.conf, there is a setting called LAST_GID, this should reflect a high number  available. Try on each machine to find a common high unused group, avoid the common upper limit by a few hundreds to avoid falling foul of a future distro having a low LAST_GID. Should both of these methods fail identify a gid say 5000, backup user uid 5000. Delete user 5000 what ever their name is, but *KEEP* their data, if applicable just delete the group.Now create your new common group with gid 5000. Now recreate user nee 5000 or the replacement group. Using the find command identify all files across the system with gid 5000, now give all these files a new gid. Remember the old 5000 is not this new public one.
Remember the whole system works on numerical gid, group names are a convenience mapping between gid and group name facilitated via file /etc/group and command groupadd.